New to fifo in linux, reading with python produces gibberish? (binary)
I am trying to grab some sensor data so I can toss it into a influxdb.  We have very old sensors writing this out to a server via a fifo on that server.  I know I can read it (made a quick program):
# reader.py
import os

FIFO = '/var/axis/sensor1'

FIFO_PATH = FIFO

fifo_path = FIFO
print("about to "+fifo_path)
# Ensure the FIFO exists
if not os.path.exists(fifo_path):
    raise IOError("The FIFO '{0}' does not exist. Please create it using 'mkfifo {0}'.".format(fifo_path))


print("Opening FIFO {0} for reading...".format(fifo_path))
fifo_fd = os.open(fifo_path, os.O_RDONLY)
fifo_file = os.fdopen(fifo_fd)

try:
  while True:
      line = fifo_file.read(1)
      if not line:
        break

    # Print the line to the screen
      print(line),

finally:
  fifo_file.close()
  print("FIFO Closed.")

So when I run this and the sensor is having data ran to I see stuff like this scroll past the screen:
@eN?>??Y?n??A?)??[Z@?c
@eN?>??\?n??A?)??[Z@?(
@eN?>`?n??A?)??[Z@??    @eN?>33c?n??A?)??[Z@??  @eN?>fff?n??A?)??[Z@??  @eN?>??i?n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>??l?n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>p?n??A?)??[Z@? @eN?>33s?n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>ffv?n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>??y?n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>??|?n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>??n??A?)??[Z@? @eN?>33??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>ff??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>?̌?n??A?)??[Z@?    @eN?>??n??A?)??[Z@? @eN?>33??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>ff??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>?̜?n??A?)??[Z@?    @eN?>??n??A?)??[Z@? @eN?>33??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>ff??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>?̬?n??A?)??[Z@?    @eN?>??n??A?)??[Z@? @eN?>33??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>ff??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>?̼?n??A?)??[Z@?    @eN?>??n??A?)??[Z@? @eN?>33??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>ff??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>??n??A?)??[Z@? @eN?>33??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>ff??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>??n??A?)??[Z@? @eN?>33??n??A?)??[Z@@eN?>ff??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>??n??A?)??[Z@? @eN?>33??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>ff??n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@?   @eN?>????n??A?)??[Z@P?  @???z?>?n??A?)??[Z@?~
@???z?>33?n??A?)??[Z@?_
                       @???z?>ff?n??A?)??[Z@??

Clearly a readline is the wrong command, I guess this data is binary? Are fifo's always binary?  If it is binary that means I have to hunt down how this old system/sensor is writing this fifo to know how to then load and parse it?
I want to know what I am reading so I know how to package it as json to send to influxdb.
EDIT: I believe I found some c code of an example of reading the data structure, with the structure can I read this in python?
C Structure of the data:
typedef struct axis_data {
    double now;
    double p;
    double v;
    double current;
    double error;
} AXIS_DATA;

fifoList.fd = open("/var/axis/sensor1", O_RDONLY);
AXIS_DATA data;
rb=read(this->fifoList.fd, &data, sizeof(data));

data.p, data.v, data.current, data.error

Paraphrased C of course, and my C is rusty but I believe I want to do the same thing with creating a structure equiv in Python and reading that structure size into the structure itself.  Somehow, in python, my attempt at that below (I cannot believe I have never done binary in python really)
# reader.py
import os
from ctypes import *

class AXIS_DATA(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('now', c_double),
                ('p', c_double),
                ('v', c_double),
                ('current', c_double),
                ('error', c_double)]




FIFO = '/var/axis/sensor1'

#FIFO = 'mytest'
FIFO_PATH = FIFO

fifo_path = FIFO
print("about to "+fifo_path)
# Ensure the FIFO exists
if not os.path.exists(fifo_path):
    raise IOError("The FIFO '{0}' does not exist. Please create it using 'mkfifo {0}'.".format(fifo_path))


print("Opening FIFO {0} for reading...".format(fifo_path))
fifo_fd = os.open(fifo_path, os.O_RDONLY)
#fifo_file = os.fdopen(fifo_fd)
fifo_file = open(fifo_path)

try:
  while True:
      result = []
      dat = AXIS_DATA()
      # this just froze
      while fifo_file.readinto(dat) == sizeof(dat):
        result.append((dat.now, dat.p, dat.v, dat.current, dat.error))
      if not line:
        break

    # Print the line to the screen
      print(result),

finally:
  fifo_file.close()
  print("FIFO Closed.")


The data in the fifo should depend on the producer, not the fact that it's a fifo.

Why are you using fdopen()? Why not just fifo_file = open(fifo_path)?

You're getting garbage because the sensor sends binary data, not text.

I was afraid of that, so I need to figure out the format to know how to parse/read it.  Ty for the info.

The struct library may be helpful.

I added more code of what I am trying to do, flying blind never attempted this but found an example using ctypes import so went with that just not sure how to read that into some data size of the data.

You don't say what the sensor is sensing? Or what it is? Try just dumping the fifo data using xxd or od with parameters set to show doubles. Try forcing the sensor to produce some kind of recognisable data by heating/cooling it, moving in just one axis and not the other, or keeping it still so only the time changes so you can start to see the various fields.

The data seems to be 5 doubles, or 40 bytes. So read 160 bytes from the fifo and you'll have 4 sets of data in which to look for patterns head -c 160 /var/axis/sensor1 | xxd If it is a movement sensor, ensure it is stationary then only time and error fields should be changing.

Are you by chance using Python 2?  (based on the print line ending with a ,)  -
You should be using Python 3 - preferably 3.11 or 3.12 - Python 2.7 has not been updated in more than 10 years.


"Are fifo's always binary?"

They are agnostic to the data that they "carry".  Just like files, sockets, etc.

If you send binary data in one end you get the same binary data out of the other end.
If you send text data with a specific encoding (ASCII, ISO-Latin, UTF-8, ...), you get back text with the same encoding.

The gibberish you are seeing looks like binary data that has been (mistakenly) read as UTF-8 encoded text.  (The ? characters are most likely substitutions for bytes / byte sequences that cannot be translated into printable characters.)
The approach of treating the data as text is unlikely to work.  Each of the ? substitutions is a place where you have lost information.  Instead, you will need to reverse engineer the binary format of the sensor's output.  (Or maybe the C struct declaration you found is sufficient.)
Once you have figured out the binary format, you should be able to read it with the help of the built-in Python struct library.

This module converts between Python values and C structs represented as Python bytes objects. Compact format strings describe the intended conversions to/from Python values. The module’s functions and objects can be used for two largely distinct applications, data exchange with external sources (files or network connections), or data transfer between the Python application and the C layer.

(The ctypes library is for a different purpose: translating data types when making function calls to external "native code" libraries / DLLs.  It won't help here.)

Hopefully there's documentation for the sensor so they don't have to reverse-engineer it.

@Barmar - There is some C code in the question including a C struct declaration which may or may not match the sensor.  The reverse engineering may be unnecessary ... in this case.

Thanks this all worked!   I got the numbers I needed thanks to the help here and the clue that the struct is likely the same (it was)

As you don't appear to be answering questions in comments, I can only roughly suggest the sort of way your code might need to look:
from struct import unpack

# Open FIFO
with open(YOURFIFO) as fd:
    # Read one frame of data, i.e. 5 doubles
    frame = fd.read(40)
    # Unpack the doubles into a tuple of 5 separate values
    values = unpack('5d', frame)
    # Print the values
    print(f'{values=}')

